# How to change imagebutton image in datalist programatically

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `Datalist` on aspx page which contains an `ImageButton` on it. I want to change its image when a user is offline versus online. Specifically, when a user is online, I want the image to be green, when offline, I want it to be red.
Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: you can use `DataList` `ItemdataBound` event

Comment: My images are not stored in databases. Only two images one for if user is logged in and other for when user is logged out.

Comment: Take a look at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.itemdatabound.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DataList.ItemDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.itemdatabound%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to go through each record and set the required image based on the value of login status.

```
void Item_Bound(Object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || 
         e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
     {
        ImageButton imagebutton = (ImageButton )e.Item.FindControl("imagebutton");
        bool onlineStatus = bool.Parse(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "OnlineStatusDbColumn").ToString());

        if(onlineStatus) 
           imagebutton.ImageURL = path1;
        else
           imagebutton.ImageURL = path2;  
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Itemcreated event of datalist.

**"The ItemCreated event  is commonly used to control the content and appearance of a row in the DataList control.(MSDN)"**